# How to dynamically update version number in chrome app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-app

I have a google chrome packaged app and I would like to update the version number on the app's about page based off of its manifest file. My manifest file is like so:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Book Writer",
  "version": "2.0.8.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/Book-icon.png",
    "48": "images/Book-icon.png",
    "128": "images/Book-icon.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

Important part being **"version": "2.0.8.0",**

and my about page is structured like so:

about.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>about</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/about.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="main-header">book writer v 2.0.8.0</h1>
    <h2 class="sub-header">This game was made by: Dragonloverlord</h2>
    <h2 class="sub-header">LICENSE</h2>
    <div class="license-div">
      <code>
        The MIT License (MIT)<br>
        <br>
        Copyright (c) 2014 dragonloverlord<br>
        <br>
        Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
        of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
        in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
        to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
        copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
        furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:<br>
        <br>
        The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
        copies or substantial portions of the Software.<br>
        <br>
        THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
        IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
        FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
        AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
        LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
        OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
        SOFTWARE.<br>
      </code>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I can not update it directly from the manifest file then is there a angularjs csp compliant method to update the number off of a single variable so all that I have to do is link a script to any page in the app that needs the version number updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update directly from the manifest: This is what the [chrome.runtime.getManifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getManifest) API is for.

In pure JavaScript, you would do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
  document.querySelector('h1.main-header').innerHTML = "book writer v " + manifest.version;
});
```

Comment: Thanks you're a life saver and wow I did not think it would be this simple! I will accept your answer the moment I can.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help. I started to write out an Angular version, but realized that it's a lot more complicated for sample code, and really depends on what the rest of your angular app looks like, so I stopped. :)

Comment: Thanks -- I forgot that it was a synchronous API -- edit accepted.